# For fixed $f \in L^2$ and $T>0$, choose $g$ so that $ \mathbb{E}^x[g(T-\tau)\chi_{X_\tau=1}]=-\mathbb{E}^x[f(X_T)\chi_{\tau \ge T}]$

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $f \in L^2(0,1)$ and $T>0$ be fixed. How can I choose $g \in L^2(0,T)$ such that
\begin{align*}
0\equiv \mathbb{E}^x\left[f\left(X_T\right) \chi_{\tau \geqslant T}+g(T-\tau) \chi_{X_\tau=1}\right] \ \ ?
\end{align*}
Here $\chi$ stands for the characteristic function of a set, $\tau := \inf\{t > 0 : X_t \not\in(0, 1)\}$, and $$
    \begin{cases}
    d X(s)= d B(s), & s \in[t, T], \\
    X(t) = x, 
    \end{cases}
$$
with $(t, x) \in[0, T) \times \mathbb{R}$ and $B(\cdot)$ a standard Brownian motion starting from $t$ (with $W(t)=0$).

Comment: Can the choice of $g$ depend on $x$ here?

Comment: @NateRiver Nope. Only on the time variable

Comment: In "Exact simulation of first exit times for one-dimensional diffusion processes", in section 1.1 talk about the joint law of the first term in the case [-1,1]. For the second term, I think you also need a joint law of tau and Xtau. then you can try to see whether such a g exists by hand.  You can also try to check Borodin's "Handbook of Brownian motion" for these joint formulas.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thanks for the reference! But do you have any intuition as to how one may choose $g$ to get the whole thing to be zero?

Comment: even in the case of indicators $f=1_{A}$ is not clear to me. If you get it for those and then simple functions, you can try an approximation argument.  Perhaps add some context/references for what you are generally trying to achieve; maybe be there is a different way around it.

Comment: What makes you think that such $g$ always exists?

Answer (score 0):

turning comment into answer

In "Exact simulation of first exit times for one-dimensional diffusion processes", in section 1.1 talk about the joint law of the first term in the case [-1,1]. For the second term, I think you also need a joint law of tau and Xtau. then you can try to see whether such a g exists by hand. You can also try to check Borodin's "Handbook of Brownian motion" for these joint formulas.

even in the case of indicators $f=1_A$  is not clear to me. If you get it for those and then simple functions, you can try an approximation argument. Perhaps add some context/references for what you are generally trying to achieve; maybe be there is a different way around it